# RestComm build and run on MAC OS from source

Tags: restcomm

I am new to restcomm two days ago i start following getting start guide and build restcomm from source. I am able to build successfully on my Mac machine but when i am trying to run JBoss server to run the application it is giving me some errors which i am not sure why. So my question is can i run restcomm application on MAC OS ?as mostly i see there are lot of answers are about linux OS.

```
MacBook-Pro:restcomm bilal$ ./start-restcomm.sh 
BASEDIR: /Users/muhammadbilal/Restcomm-Connect/release/Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.0.2/bin/restcomm
RESTCOMM_HOME: /Users/muhammadbilal/Restcomm-Connect/release/Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.0.2
Looking for the appropriate interface
Looking for the IP Address, subnet, network and broadcast_address
Use of uninitialized value $ARGV[0] in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/local/bin/ipcalc line 136.

RestComm automatic configuration started:
Executing configuration file /Users/muhammadbilal/Restcomm-Connect/release/Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.0.2/bin/restcomm/autoconfig.d/config-dialogic-xms.sh...
Configuring Dialogic XMS...MS_MODE: mms
...activated Dialogic XMS...
...finished configuring Dialogic XMS!
Finished executing configuration file /Users/muhammadbilal/Restcomm-Connect/release/Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.0.2/bin/restcomm/autoconfig.d/config-dialogic-xms.sh!

Executing configuration file /Users/muhammadbilal/Restcomm-Connect/release/Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.0.2/bin/restcomm/autoconfig.d/config-jboss-as.sh...
Configuring JBoss AS...
...disabled JBoss splash screen...
Finished configuring JBoss AS!
Finished executing configuration file /Users/muhammadbilal/Restcomm-Connect/release/Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.0.2/bin/restcomm/autoconfig.d/config-jboss-as.sh!

Executing configuration file /Users/muhammadbilal/Restcomm-Connect/release/Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.0.2/bin/restcomm/autoconfig.d/config-load-balancer.sh...
Deactivated Load Balancer on SIP stack configuration file
Finished executing configuration file /Users/muhammadbilal/Restcomm-Connect/release/Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.0.2/bin/restcomm/autoconfig.d/config-load-balancer.sh!

Executing configuration file /Users/muhammadbilal/Restcomm-Connect/release/Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.0.2/bin/restcomm/autoconfig.d/config-mobicents-ms.sh...
TRUSTSTORE_FILE is not set
Configuring Mobicents Media Server... MS_ADDRESS  BIND_ADDRESS  NETWORK 192.168.1.0 SUBNET_MASK  RTP_LOW_PORT 34534 RTP_HIGH_PORT 65535
Configured UDP Manager
Updated log configuration
Finished configuring Mobicents Media Server!
Finished executing configuration file /Users/muhammadbilal/Restcomm-Connect/release/Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.0.2/bin/restcomm/autoconfig.d/config-mobicents-ms.sh!

Executing configuration file /Users/muhammadbilal/Restcomm-Connect/release/Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.0.2/bin/restcomm/autoconfig.d/config-restcomm.sh...
Configuring RestComm...
Updated mobicents-dar properties
Updated RestComm configuration
Configured Fax Service credentials
Configured Sms Aggregator using OUTBOUND PROXY 
Configured the Speech Recognizer
Configured Acapela Speech Synthesizer
Configured VoiceRSS Speech Synthesizer
Disabled TeleStax Proxy
sed: 1: "/Users/muhammadbilal/Re ...": invalid command code m
Configured SMPP Account Details
Configured RestComm!
Finished executing configuration file /Users/muhammadbilal/Restcomm-Connect/release/Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.0.2/bin/restcomm/autoconfig.d/config-restcomm.sh!

Executing configuration file /Users/muhammadbilal/Restcomm-Connect/release/Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.0.2/bin/restcomm/autoconfig.d/config-sip-connectors.sh...
Configuring Application Server...
Configured SIP Connectors and Bindings
sed: 1: "/Users/muhammadbilal/Re ...": invalid command code m
Configured gather-statistics
TRUSTSTORE_FILE is not set
Finished configuring Application Server!
Finished executing configuration file /Users/muhammadbilal/Restcomm-Connect/release/Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.0.2/bin/restcomm/autoconfig.d/config-sip-connectors.sh!

RestComm automatic configuration finished!

./start-restcomm.sh: line 182: ${MS_EXTERNAL^^}: bad substitution
TelScale RestComm started running on standalone mode. Screen session: restcomm.
Using IP Address:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can run Restcomm on Mac OSX, the main difference is that you need to do some more configuration manually since the auto configuration scripts don't work there as well as they do for GNU/Linux.

Please check this guide:

https://github.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Connect/wiki/Restcomm-OSX-native-installation

If you still have issues after trying such configuration, please post back here.

Best regards,
Antonis Tsakiridis

Comment: Fantastic! it works i was missing the # Network configuration part due to which i am unable to start it. Now i can see the application page. This problem solve but now default usename and password is not working to login into the application i am looking for solution finger crossed!

Comment: @Bilal please mark the question as accepted if it solved your question, so that community can better understand :). Also can you provide more details on your latest issue to see if I can help?

Comment: Thanks a lot again Antonis! Actually now server is running and url – http://IP:8080/ and i am trying to login with default username and password.username=administrator@company.com and the password=RestComm. But it is saying credentials are not correct. I am also seeing logs to see any error but there is not error in the log file.

Comment: After doing some testing this service not found Http 404 http://127.0.0.1:8080/restcomm/2012-04-24/Accounts.json/administrator@company.com means something is not running properly.I run the application using localhost IP address. One more thing in the last wiki post you mention Add VOICERSS key in restcomm.conf from where i can get this key? currently i am using the key which is mention on Dockers installation guide.

Comment: @Bilal please do the following: 1. stop Restcomm-Connect (for Mac OSX there's a known issue that doesn't allow the stop-restcomm.sh script to work, so you 'll have to find out the java processes of Restcomm-Connect and Media Server and kill them :(), 2. Empty the log file at RESTCOMM_CONNECT_INSTALLATION_DIR/standalone/log/server.log, 3. Start Restcomm-connect with start-restcomm.sh, 4. Try to login via AdminUI (i.e. http://127.0.0.1:8080/), 5. Paste the contents of server.log either to pastebin or gist so that we can have a look. A screen shot of the browser with error will help also. Thanks!

Comment: I downloaded the latest release from https://mobicents.ci.cloudbees.com/job/RestComm/896/ and that is working fine but the one which i build on my system using latest source code is creating problem